# Writing multiple python rasterio xarray results to file and naming each raster file

Tags: python, rasterio, rioxarray

I am relatively new in using python for GIS, but I have the following code that I use to clip all created mosaics by a shapefile (aoi_shapefile).  After the clipped rasters are placed in the rasterio xarray I would like to write each result to disk, but name each element in the xarray with the filenames clipped_mosaic_b2, clipped_mosaic_b4, clipped_mosaic_b5, clipped_mosaic_b6, clipped_mosaic_b8.   I believe it can be done with a for loop, but haven't a clue on how to start it off.

```
# --- Clipping Task ---

# Directory of mosaics

mosaic_dir = r"C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Land Suitability Model\Layers\Sentinel\Sentinel RST"

# Create list of all mosaics

# Search for all mosaic images in directory & glob images to a list

mosaic_query = "mosaic_*.tif"
mosaic_images = os.path.join(mosaic_dir, mosaic_query)
mosaic_list = glob.glob(mosaic_images)
mosaics_to_clip = []


# open all mosaics using rioxarray
for all_mosaics in mosaic_list:
    rxr_array = rxr.open_rasterio(all_mosaics)
    mosaics_to_clip.append(rxr_array)

# For loop to clip all open rasters
clipped_mosaics =[]
for i in mosaics_to_clip:
    clipped = i.rio.clip(aoi_shapefile.geometry.apply(mapping))
    clipped_mosaics.append(clipped)
    
for j in clipped_mosaics:
    show(j)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rio.to_raster` method should do what you want:
https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html